# Avoid converting XML special characters with SAX parser

Tags: xml, special-characters, sax

I'm using a SAX parser (ContentHandler) to parse some XML.

Is it possible to preserve special XML characters?

For example instead of parsing `&amp;` as `&`, is it possible to keep the `&amp;`?

Comment: No. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: the system i'm feeding the xml into expects escaped special characters (&amp; etc..) The content handler gives me the unescaped special characters. So it's not possible?

Comment: No, you'll have to re-escape them.

Comment: ok thanks. Can you add an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that I think. But note that you have `org.xml.sax.EntityResolver` to do a custom resolution of external entities (not `&amp;` and the likes) and you also have `org.xml.sax.ext.LexicalHandler` to get infos about the start end end of an entity if your SaX implementation got it. I think it might be helpful in locating the entities.

You could also reintroduce all entity references as suggested by @MichaelKay